Water Sprinkler eventually goes to Zero water
I have a well with a 40-60 pressure tank.
I have a manifold with 2 hose bibs.
One bib has large sand filter, and the sprinkler attached to the end of that.
Nothing is attached to the other bib.
I water with a big Rainbird impact sprinkler.
It is natural for the water volume at the sprinkler head to fluctuate as the pressure tank moves from 60 - 40.
What happens in my case is the sprinkler eventually goes down to a dribble.
If I open the other hose bib, water shoots out with great pressure.
I shut off the sprinkler and open the end clean out valve, flush it and close it.
Turn the water back on and the sprinkler starts working with great water pressure.
NOTE: the sand filter is NOT clogged.  There is no sand in the filter.
That would be the obvious reason and if true, I would not be posting this puzzle.
Do I have a vaper lock or something going on?
Thanks for your thoughts.

Possibly it is some feedback (or lack of it). Low pressure, so less water flow out of sprinker, and so pump will not increase pressure )low flow), and so it keep low. On the second case: there is flow, so pump will work, and so more pressure, more flow in the sprinkler, and so it continue high. Check documentation of minimal (ideal) flow, and maybe adapt/add sprinkler to get such flow. Or an automatic drain (so empty pipes when not in use, which cause flow and pressure)

@GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you for your feedback.  I have confirmed the low pressure was sand build up in the filter.  I thought I could detect sand by opening the filter cleanout port, but could not.  After pulling the filter off and inspecting it I could tell it is micro sand clogging the filter.
